# wpf translating point relative to the window results in a offset when moving the UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf, events, blend

I was currently working on a behavior class for dragging UIElements with the mouse. I had made something like this before but I was trying to make it so that the UIElement is not depending on having a certain type of parent (besides a window).

The problem I was facing was when I tried to translate the coordinates of both the mouse and the UIElement(AssociatedObject) relative to the window, which resulted in a offset shown down below.

Trying to add offsets to "fix" the current offset feels like a cheat and it would make creating the rest of the movement behavior a lot more complicated.

currently I am using a grid with multiple elements inside for testing the dragBehaviorComponentClass.
(I filled the grid in with lightBlue to act as an indicator, although it is slightly overlapped by other shapes)

[image: the oddly shaped form is the UIElement]
[image: UIElement: X 788/ Y 345 || Mouse: x 786 / Y 310]

I am currently only trying to attach the 0,0 position of the uiElement to the point of the mouse, I am not working on any offsets yet to further improve dragging.

**Code**

```
public class MouseDragBehaviourComponent : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        private TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonDown += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown;
            AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseMove += AssociatedObject_PreviewMouseMove;
            AssociatedObject.MouseMove += AssociatedObject_MouseMove;
            AssociatedObject.MouseLeftButtonUp += AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            AssociatedObject.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }
        private void AssociatedObject_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

        {
            Point currentPosition = AssociatedObject.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject));
            AssociatedObject.RenderTransform = transform;
            AssociatedObject.CaptureMouse();
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AssociatedObject.IsMouseCaptured)
            {
                Point mousePosition = e.GetPosition(Window.GetWindow(AssociatedObject));
                transform.X = mousePosition.X;
                transform.Y = mousePosition.Y;
            }

        }
```

**xaml**

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate  TargetType="{x:Type local:UISet}">
                    <Border >
                        <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <bt:MouseDragBehaviourComponent/>
                        </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Grid Background="LightBlue">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Path MouseLeftButtonDown="geometry_MouseLeftButtonDown" Name="geometry" Fill="Blue">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                    <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Rect="-5,-50,100,50" />
                                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                            <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" Rect="5,-40,90,40" />
                                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                    </CombinedGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                            <Path MouseLeftButtonDown="geometry_MouseLeftButtonDown" Fill="Red">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <PathGeometry>
                                        <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <LineSegment Point="5,6"/>
                                            <LineSegment Point="10,0"/>
                                            <LineSegment Point="0,0"/>
                                        </PathFigure>
                                    </PathGeometry>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
```

Comment: Why not just use the `MouseDragElementBehavior` from the Blend SDK and save the headache?

Comment: I actually want to be able to do a lot more than only move them around, changing from snapping movement to normal movement to displacing multiple controls depending on the state. Although I didn't think I had to include this since it wasn't really a part of the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way your code is set up:

```
transform.X = mousePosition.X;
transform.Y = mousePosition.Y;
```

gets the mouse position inside of the thing your moving. This causes the transform to move away from the mouse whatever that distance is. To fix that, you need to get the mouse position of the container of the thing you're moving which will act as the main point, and also get the mouse position of the cursor inside of the thing you're moving. This will act as the offset. So in all, the code will look something similar to:

```
Point mouseContainerLocation = Mouse.GetPosition(container);
Point mouseObjectLocation = Mouse.GetPosition(object);
transform.X = mouseContainerLocation.X - mouseObjectLocation.X;
transform.Y = mouseContainerLocation.Y - mouseObjectLocation.Y;
```

I did something similar in an application I made and this worked for me

Comment: Can you still get this to work with using the window as the container, else you would have to go up the visual tree to find a compatible parent. I tried this and the control would jump off the screen. 

I was using the Window.getWindow(associatedObject) as the container which gets the MainWindow. Then I used the associatedObject as the "object".

The uiElement completely jumps off screen.

Comment: If you use `Mouse.GetPosition(null)` it will return the mouse position relative to the window